# Devise: prevent some flash messages from being saved in session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

When using Devise, redirects to login page are accompanied by a "you need to sign in or login." flash. This is saved in a session.

For various reasons I can't control, I got *LOTS* of programmatic access to pages doing that, each one creating a session and filling a lot of space on database (where I'm saving sessions).

From what I understand, a simple solution would be to just avoid saving that flash message in session, thus preventing its creation at all.

It's ok for me to save it somewhere else, like a dedicated cookie, even in clear, or just skip its creations at all, as my UX won't worsen that much (redirecting a user to the Login form is already a very clear message of what he has to do).

What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: I have never heard of a `flash` being saved in a session. Are you sure this is accurately your issue? Now when you bounce from a page to the login screen other information is stored in the session like the url you were trying to visit when you were redirected. This allows the user to login and be taken back to the page they were attempting to access.

Comment: I'm seeing the flash data being saved in the session data on DB. Where would you expect it to be saved between page views?

Comment: Sorry My first comment was misleading. What I meant by "Saved" was long term persistence. The flash object is part of the session but extremely temporary e.g. just between the redirect and the page load and then the message is removed. The message should not last, in the session, beyond the next page load  so I am unsure why this would be a concern.

Comment: That is absolutely correct, but you're assuming I get only legitimate visits from browsers. Instead, I'm getting access from scripts, most of them being malevolent attempt to access pages that does not exists, that does not honor any redirect instruction, and the session ends up being there forever.